# How do I search for an array of user input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I really need your help

How do I search for an array of user input in javascript?

The following is the array script:

```
var items = [
            ["0001", "Roman", "Reading"],
            ["0002", "Ryan", Playing the Guitar "],
            ["0003", "Wiley", "Cooking"],
            ["0004", "Jack", "Gardening"]
        ]
```

Can you give me examples of html and javascript scripts. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess you should better understand the way SO works. You have to take the first step and try to solve the issue and then show us what you have tried, why you tried that, what results you are getting and in which way is it different from the expected results!!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to understand what you want to achieve. Please provide some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you mean only usernames out of this array??

Comment: Please define how you want to search (partial string match? full phase match? whole cell match?), what result you want (simple true/false? row index? row and cell?), and show us the code you tried but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this kind of search would be made with objects but because you have given us an array this function searches results from an array.

First we need a filter string. Then we loop through arrays and check if string includes filter string. If it includes it we push result to results array.

JS

```
                var items = [
                ["0001", "Roman", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Ryan", "Playing the Guitar"],
                ["0003", "Wiley", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Jack", "Gardening"]
            ];

            function handleSearch() {
                var value = document.getElementById('searchValue').value;
                var results = [];
                if (value) {
                    items.forEach(item => {
                        item.forEach(itemString => {
                            if (itemString.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                                results.push(`${value} found in ${itemString} in block ${item}`);
                            };
                        });
                    });
                    console.log(results);
                }
            }
```

HTML

```
    <input id="searchValue"/>
    <button onclick="handleSearch()">Search</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a script that will output the index of the child array within the parent array:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "equals", {
    "value": function(target) {
        let sourceProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
        let targetProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target);
        let comparer = function(value, index, source) {
            return this[value] === target[value];
        };
        if(sourceProperties.length === targetProperties.length)
            return sourceProperties.every(comparer, this);
        else
            return false;
    }
});
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "findObject", {
    "value": function(objectToFind) {
        let comparer = function(value, index, source) {
            return value.equals(objectToFind);
        };
        return this.findIndex(comparer);
    }
});
let items = [
                ["0001", "Roman", "Reading"],
                ["0002", "Ryan", "Playing the Guitar"],
                ["0003", "Wiley", "Cooking"],
                ["0004", "Jack", "Gardening"]
            ];
console.log(items.findObject(["0002", "Ryan", "Playing the Guitar"]));
```

Answer (score -1):

First, set an id to the input tag and set 'onkeyup' event to a JS function.

```
<input id="searchInput" onkeyup="Search()">
```

In JS, get the input entered by using getElementById. Using filter method, filter the items array. use toLowerCase() to ignore case entered.

```
var items = [
        ["0001", "Roman", "Reading"],
        ["0002", "Ryan", "Playing the Guitar "],
        ["0003", "Wiley", "Cooking"],
        ["0004", "Jack", "Gardening"]
    ]
function Search(){
    var input = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();

    var filteredArray = items.filter(x=> x[1].toLowerCase().includes(input));
    console.log(filteredArray); //will display the filtered array according to the user input
}
```